# the rules for the usage of "regardless"

Tags: adverbs

*Regardless of their guilt or innocence, they did not get a fair trial.*

I am not sure if this is OK in terms of grammar to rewrite the above sentence this way.

*Regardless (of) they were guilty or innocent, they did not get a fair trial.*

Is it possible that a full sentence comes after *"regardless"*. And if so, is the preposition "of" needed?

Comment: The object of **of** in "regardless of" is a nominal of some kind.  Regardless of *the fact* that they may have been guilty....regardless of *their guilt or innocence*...

Comment: If you want to use a clause, *they were guilty or innocent,* instead of using *their guilt or innocence*, you need to use *whether*: *regardless **of whether** they were....*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using *'regardless'* in the beginning of a sentence is perfectly acceptable, and infact, is used extensively by many people.

To understand the usage of the word *'regardless'*, try going through [these examples](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/regardless). Notice how almost all sentences that use the word *'regardless'* is followed by the preposition *'of'*.

One can roughly translate *"Regardless of"* as **'Even though'**.

It is generally seen that *'regardless'* is usually succeeded by an *'of'* when used in a sentence. There may be sentences that omits the preposition after *'regardless'*, none of which are in my head though. So, one can say that this is a general rule, but yes, there can/ may be exceptions.

It is a general usage to say *"Regardless of something"*.

Try going through [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43335/the-usage-of-regardless-of) and [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54691/regardless-of-meaning-and-using-in-sentence) also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have still doubts regarding my second sentence. Is not a better choice this version: Regardless of whether they were guilty or innocent, they did not get a fair trial.

Comment: That sounds okay, but if you can convey something with a smaller number of words, it is far more efficient. The meaning hardly changes if the sentence "*Regardless of their guilt or innocence, they did not get a fair trial*" is reframed as *"Regardless of whether they were guilty or innocent, they did not get a fair trial."*.

Comment: We could say "Whether they were guilty or innocent, they did not..."

Comment: @TRomano, yes, *"Regardless of their guilt or innocence, they did not..."* and *"Whether they were guilty or innocent, they did not..."* are widely used, when compared to *"Regardless of whether they....."*

Comment: We could even say "Guilty or innocent, they did not..."  :)